# How to compare 2 lists in xunit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit

I am using Assert.Equal(expected,actual) in my unit testing.Eventhough the lists and the order are same it is failing.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DeepEqual`](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual) NuGet package and then in the code:

```
actual.ShouldDeepEqual(expected);
```

Another option would be to use [`FluentAssertions`](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions) NuGet package and then in the code:

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Comment: I tried the above working fine for me but not able to compare in order.Is there any way to compare the lists in order ?

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use `Assert.True( listOne.SequenceEqual( listTwo ) )`.

The downsides are neither list can be null and the results do not indicate a detailed reason for the failure if the test fails.